# How to add name attribute in vue component with an error?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I get an error on the screenshot.

[image: error message]

How can I provide the name attribute on this code in my app.js?

**app.js**

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('table-logs', require('./components/TableLogs.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**TableLogs.vue**

```html
<template>
    <vuetable ref="vuetable" 
        api-url="https://vuetable.ratiw.net/api/users"
        :fields="['name', 'nickname', 'email', 'gender']" 
        data-path=""
        pagination-path="">
    </vuetable>
</template>

<script>
    import Vuetable from 'vuetable-2'

    export default {
        components: {
            Vuetable
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can i see your TableLogs file

Comment: @Merouane Boucenna Yes, you can see it now above. I've updated my question.

Comment: Why are you mixing `import` and `require` for components?

Comment: Where? I can see that they're 2 different files @Phil

Comment: In `TableLogs.vue` you `import` `VueTable` but in `app.js`, you `require` `TableLogs`.

Comment: What does your `<div id="app">` element look like? What elements are inside it?

Comment: `<div id="app">
    <table-logs></table-logs>
</div>` Just this. I only called the component, table-logs

Answer (score 0):

Provide the "name" attribute in your component.

`
    import Vuetable from 'vuetable-2'

```
export default {
    name: 'myTestComponent',
    components: {
        Vuetable
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how Laravel and Vue work together but in a typical Vue CLI generated project, you add your root component using a render function. For example

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

```js
// app.js
require('./bootstrap'); // I imagine this is required

import TableLogs from './components/TableLogs.vue'

new Vue({
  render: h => h(TableLogs),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still has the same error.

Comment: Did you change your HTML as indicated in my answer?

Comment: No, I discontinued this solution and resorted to another one

Comment: So you didn't do what was in my answer and were surprised it didn't work?

Comment: Lol. I change the HTML as indicated but got the same issue.

Comment: The exact same error message? With my answer, there's no way you would get _"Unknown custom element `<table-logs>`"_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201371/discussion-between-jumar-juaton-and-phil).